# Pop up message window title in ASP.NET

Tags: messagebox

I am using the code mentioned below to pop up a message.

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "msg", "alert('"+s+"');", true);
```

This is working fine, but I want to change the title of the window. Presently the title of the pop up window is "the page at localhost says:". But I want to change this. Is there any way through by which I can change the title of the pop up window.

Comment: Is your popup window javascript alert window or browser popup window?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the JavaScript alert box header name. But instead you can use one of many  existing frameworks. For example [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

Here it comes

```
Page.Header.Title =  DateTime.Now.ToString();
```